# Using Laravel container for repositories

Tags: php, laravel, containers, ioc-container, laravel-5

I'm working with repositories lately and I'm trying to solve some default actions or needed behaviour in the main repository which is named `AbstractRepository`.

The `AbstractRepository` looks like this:

```
class AbstractRepository
{
  protected $session;
  protected $loggedUser;

  public function __construct(Session $session)
  {
     $this->session = $session->current();
     $this->loggedUser = $session->currentUser();
  }
}
```

In every repository I want to be able to use these properties, but then I must call `parent::__construct()` in every repository to execute the constructor.

Is there any way I am able to let laravel's container handle this, instead of calling the parent constructor in every repository?

So I could just do it like this:

```
class CommentRepository extends AbstractRepository implements ICommentRepository
{
  public function like($commentId)
  {
    $entry = Like::where('comment_id', $commentId)->where('user_id', $this->loggedUser->id);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the class that extends another (abstract) class doesn't override the parent constructor the constructor of the parent class will be automatically called.

So if you had something like this:

```
class CommentRepository extends AbstractRepository implements ICommentRepository
{
    public function __construct(Session $session){
        $this->foo = 'bar';
    }
}
```

You would have to add `parent::__construct()` if you wanted the constructor in `AbstractRespository` to be called.

```
public function __construct(Session $session){
    parent::__construct($session);
    $this->foo = 'bar';
}
```

However if your constructor method just looks like this, you can delete it completely:

```
public function __construct(Session $session){
    parent::__construct($session);
}
```